# Multigraph software

Tags: graph, network-analysis

do you know any good software that manages multigraph? My aim is to display it, compute some metrics on it (when well defined), import/export from common network formats (GraphML...) and so on.
Something like Gephi or NetSocV but with multigraph support.
Linux support would be great.

I found NetworkX for Python and it seems good, but I was wondering if there are alternatives available.

Any recommendations?